# Delete Field Editor

Tags: field-editor

Just wondering if you can delete Field Editor without it running into issues with fields created with it.

Looking to upgrade to EE3 and Field Editor isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall it with no problem. Your fields will remain intact.